# prefilled share page on Facebook

Tags: facebook, share

My client has requested to replace the automatic share functionality on his app. At the moment it uses `publish_stream` permission to post on behalf of the client once he clicks the share button.

Instead, the client wants a page residing on Facebook with prefilled data (possibly fetched from remote a URL using OG). However, I didn't find in the docs how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in the doc here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

and here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Try this example and replace your data, then just redirect the user to that url:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response

Edit: also it isn't possible to prefill your message anymore, as of [this update](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is to use something like [this](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=blackbox-iphone.com&t=%3Ctitle%20of%20content%3E)